# How to use Skype Web SDK with Skype (not Skype for Business)

Tags: skype, skypedeveloper

How to use Skype Web SDK with Skype? The documentation says:

> The Skype Developer Platform for Web ("Skype Web SDK") is a set of JavaScript Web APIs and HTML controls that enable you to build web experiences that seamlessly integrate a wide variety of real-time collaboration models leveraging Skype for Business services **and the larger Skype network**. It provides support for multiple core collaboration services like presence, chat, audio, and video, enabling web experiences across a broad spectrum of users, platforms, and devices.

but the sample login code doesn't work. I have no log entry in the browser console. Skype LoginState is SigningIn.

I want to integrate Skype video chat in an ASP.NET web site.

Any help is appreciated.